# How do I get set cookie value when there are multiple set cookie request in varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to unset cookie if my cookie has certain value.
I tried getting the value using `beresp.http.Set-Cookie` but this seems to get first value set in Set-Cookie on response. Is there any way I can pull the second Set-Cookie's value ?
Edit

This is my Response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2021 09:47:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12297
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: br
Set-Cookie: VarnishCustomerIsGuest=True; path=/
Set-Cookie: .Nop.Customer=62a224b9-3b5b-4e74-8200-cf341df111af; expires=Sat, 19 Feb 2022 09:47:53 GMT; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: .Nop.TempData=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["4f9a095d-bbd1-4ffe-81e1-31761363af25"]
X-TMP1000: VarnishCustomerIsGuest=True; path=/
X-Varnish: 163854
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
X-Cache: MISS
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

What I am trying to do is get the customer cookie at vcl_backend_response. But

```
beresp.http.Set-Cookie
```

gives me the first set-cookie value of VarnishCustomerIsGuest and I am not sure if I can get the customer cookie .Nop.Customer.

My application backend always sets cookie for every request so  what I am trying to do is unset the cookies depending on .Nop.Customer value so that for some particular customer the page is always served from the varnish cache.

Comment: Please add the relevant VCL code in which you extract values from `beresp.http.Set-Cookie`. This will help me understand your problem, and will allow me to help you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited the question and tried to be little more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish's `vmod_std` has the [`std.collect()`](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vmod_generated.html#func-collect) function that collapses headers into a single header.

In your case, the following VCL snippet could be used to collapse all occurrences of the `Set-Cookie` header into a single `Set-Cookie`:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

sub vcl_backend_response {
    std.collect(beresp.http.Set-Cookie);    
}
```

Of course your existing VCL logic should be part of the VCL file as well. This example just shows the  need to import the VMOD and to call `std.collect()` within `vcl_backend_response`.

An important disclaimer that comes directly from the [`std.collect()` documentation page](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vmod_generated.html#func-collect):

> Care should be taken when collapsing headers. In particular collapsing Set-Cookie will lead to unexpected results on the browser side.

Once the `Set-Cookie` header is collapsed, you can use `regsub()` logic to extract the necessary values.